# What does "last month" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, this-last

Let me explain the situation. Today is Oct 31, 2012. After I got my October pay-slip yesterday I had the following conversation:

> Me: Hey guy, I have a question to ask you about the pay-slip of the last month. I think the number is incorrect.
>   X: It is $10, is it correct?
>   Me: No, I mean last month (I mean September) not this month.
>   X: Last month? Okay.

I want to know, did I use "last month" correctly in this case? I used "last month" because this month is not passed yet, so I used it to refer to the month before this month. And if it is incorrect, what word should I use.

Comment: Technically you are right , last month should be September. In most of the companies payroll is decided till 20<sup>th</sup> of the month , maybe it has something to do with that. I am also eager to know, waiting for someone's comment on that.

Comment: In this situation, *last month* is September, *the last month* is October.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the confusion by referring to the payslip instead of mixing in calendar months. Last pay slip or current pay slip and previous pay slip. Pay slip for date ending xxxx. Pay periods do not follow the irregular nature of the months.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the phrase **"last month"** was correct. Since you asked about **"last month's pay slip"** and the date of your question was **October 31st**, it is implied that **last month** of which you spoke was September. Therefore, the pay slip in question was distributed during the month of September.

You may also use the phrase **"the previous month"** in lieu of **"last month"**.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about "last month's pay slip", they asked about "the pay slip of the last month". Adding "the" before "last" changes the meaning.