# "In the last month" vs. "last month"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> 1. I have seen that movie six times **in** the last month.
> 2. I have seen that movie six times last month.

Why?

Comment: Related (possible dupe): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/89632/8019

Answer (score 13):

Today is October 12th.

If you say "I have seen the movie six times in the last month", you have seen it six times since September 12th.

If you say "I have seen that movies six times last month" you saw it six times in September.

Also... you should not mix present perfect with a time phrase.  "I have seen that movie six times last month" should be worded "I saw the movie six times last month". This is because present perfect has a connection with the present, but last month is past.

Comment: If I don't use present perfect with a time phrase then both sentences are wrong? Sorry kindly elaborate on this. Thank you

Comment: Opposite... if you use a time-phrase, you should match it with past simple: "I saw the movie last month".

Comment: If the time phrase refers to _finished_ time, then the present perfect cannot be used. If we are in October then "_last month_" refers to September, which is finished time - so the past simple is needed. The phrase "_in the last month_" means "_in the thirty or so days up to and including today_". This is not a phrase of finished time, so the present perfect can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when you use "last" with "have seen" 
it can't be used together, so much better to use past tense like 
"I saw that movies six times last month"